# -- swift: async + JSON + completion + DispatchGroup

Tags: json, swift, asynchronous, dispatch-async, completion

The code in my viewcontroller-class is executed **before** the JSON-download-process is ready even though there is a completion handler in the func for downloading JSON an a DispatchGroup(). I store the JSON-data in an array called "fetchedModules" and this is filled with 11 items in this case. Why does this happen?

```
result in console:
---> in Class PostCell - func numberOfSections: 0
JSON call finished 

// ViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()

    self.fetchJSON()
    // here calling downloadJSONasync

    group.leave()

    group.notify(queue: .main)  {
        print("JSON call finished")
    }

    ...

    // networkService with completion
    func downloadJSONasync(searchItem: String, completion: @escaping ([NSDictionary]) -> Void) {

    //request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    //let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil)

    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

        if (error != nil) {
            print("error!")
        }

        else{

            do {

                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [NSDictionary]

                completion(fetchedData)

            }

            catch {
                print("error")
            }

        }

    })

    task.resume()

}

// call in viewController
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    print("---> in Class PostCell - func numberOfSections: \(String(describing: fetchedModules.count))")
    return fetchedModules.count

// code of fetchJSON
func fetchJSON()
{

    let baseurl = AppConstants.Domains.baseurl // https://m.myapp2go.de

    let compositURL = baseurl + "getmodules_noItems.php?id=\(AppConstants.appString.startString)"

    let encodedUrl : String! = compositURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) // remove the spaces in the url string for safty reason

    let JSONurl = URL(string: encodedUrl)! // convert the string into url

    var JSONrequest = URLRequest(url: JSONurl) // make request

    JSONrequest.httpMethod = "GET"

    //JSONrequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData

    let networkService = NetworkService(request: JSONrequest)

    networkService.downloadJSONasync(searchItem: AppConstants.appString.startString, completion: { (fetchedData) in

        fetchedModules.removeAll()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            for eachFetchedModul in fetchedData {

                let eachModul = eachFetchedModul

                if

                    let custid    = eachModul["custid"]    as? String,
                    let modulcat  = eachModul["modulcat"]  as? String,
                    let modulname = eachModul["modulname"] as? String,
                    let comment   = eachModul["comment"]   as? String

                {

                    fetchedModules.append(CModules(custid: custid, modulcat: modulcat, modulname: modulname, comment: comment))

                    print(custid)
                    print(modulcat)
                    print(modulname)
                    print(comment)

                    print("---------------------")
                }

            }// for end

            // ... somehow set data source array for your table view
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }// dispatch



    }


)} // func end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `fetchJSON` returns immediately, before the JSON is downloaded. The effect is that the `DispatchGroup` is entereed and left right away, without waiting for the JSON:

```
group.enter()
self.fetchJSON() // returns immediately
group.leave()    // the JSON has yet to be downloaded
```

To wait until the JSON has arrived, add a completion handler to `fetchJSON`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    group.enter()
    self.fetchJSON { 
        group.notify(queue: .main)  {
            print("JSON call finished")
        }
        group.leave()
    }
}

// Change the data type of the completion handler accordingly
func fetchJSON(completionHandler: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
    // ...
    networkService.downloadJSONasync(searchItem: AppConstants.appString.startString) { fetchedData in
        defer { completionHandler(fetchedData) }
        // ...
    }
)
```

Using `defer` ensures that the completion handler will always be called, no matter how the outer closure returns. I'm not clear why you use a `DispatchGroup` here as there is no waiting, but I kept it in place to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Building with your code i get the error in func fetchJSON: **Cannot convert value of type '[NSDictionary]' to expected argument type 'Data?'**  Must the completionHandler have the type NSDictionary and not Data? Do i not have tu use DispatchGroup at all in this place ?

Comment: Change the `completionHandler` signature to use `[NSDictionary]`. i didn't know what data type `fetchedData` was. And no, I didn't see any reason why you need a Dispatch Group in the code.

Comment: OK, sorry, you wrote this in your comment. So i can omit the DispatchGroup (enter, notify, leave) completely?

Comment: Ups, i changed the data type to my type NSDictionary with the message: **Cannot convert value of type '[NSDictionary]' to expected argument type 'NSDictionary'** Whats to do now?

Comment: You forgot the brackets

Comment: Sorry, there were missing [] at the NSDictionary.

Comment: yes, thanks:) One last Question: in the func downloadJSONasync is the code **  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        completion(fetchedData)
                    }** . Is this OK then?

Comment: I don't see you `downloadJSONasync` but you are firing off that completion handler on the main queue. I generally avoid touching the main queue except for GUI update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188302/discussion-between-ralf-borde-and-code-different).

Answer (score 1):

Your table view doesn't have any data from the beginning because any data hasn't been fetched yet. So it's ok, that table view has no cells. You just need to `reloadData` of your table view since now you appended elements to table view's data source array and now you should show this data.

---

Please, don't use `DispatchGroup` for this, just use your `completion` parameter of your method and inside of the `completion` closure after data are received set data source array for table view and then ... reload data of table view

```
downloadJSONasync(searchItem: "someString") { dictionary in
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // don't forget that your code doesn't run on the main thread
        // ... somehow set data source array for your table view
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Note that you should avoid using `NSDictonary` and you should rather use `Dictionary`. Also from Swift 4+ you can use `Codable` instead of `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your suggestion. I can not do " self.tableView.reloadData()" be cause i am in another class **"networkService"**. Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'tableView'. What do you mean with "... somehow set data source array for your table view" ? I fill my data-array (JSON-array) outside this class "netwokService" And i will try to use Dictionary inst. of NSDictionary.

Comment: @RalfBordé ok, then add completion for `fetchJSON` and completion call after completion of `downloadJSONasync` is called

Comment: you mean i should call the DispatchQueue.main.async ... in my function **fetchJSON**? How can i paste code here in my comment ? possible?

Comment: @RalfBordé no I don't. You should add `completion` parameter for `fetchJSON` too and in this closure you should set and reload data of table view

Comment: OK, i Will try. now it gets more complicated ...  puh

Comment: @RalfBordé if you added code of `fetchJSON` to your question, maybe I could help you

Comment: i have tried to add code. It's too long and i dont know which markdown i have to use in comment ? sorry.

Comment: @RalfBordé ````

Comment: i have added it in the original question.

Comment: @RalfBordé man, you don't have to set data source array if you append elements. So... just use `self.tableView.reloadData()` that should be all

Comment: what do you mean with data source array? My array fetchedModules? But i have to fill it with my fetchedData.

Comment: @RalfBordé yes! And this is what you do. You're appending elements. So you don't want to do this. Just reload data

Comment: hm... in my controller (prototypCell) i fill the Labels with the data from **fetchedModules**. If this is empty , all is empty. Could this be the right way? If you have the time please have a closer look on the code. Thank you a lot.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will check it. Yes i will accept the answer.